# iOS 11 - Send Firebase Cloud Message through Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

1. I'm trying to send push notifications when listening to an onWrite event at a database reference. The value of the event is being written to due to a cron job that runs daily.
2. I'm also trying to get the body message to display a string based off of the _random index value. I'm using the _random index value to get the database reference key at index.

Can anyone help?

```
exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('_random').onWrite(event => {

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Title',
            body: `Test`, //use _random to get key at index key
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        }
    };

    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24, //24 hours
        content_available: true
    };
    console.log('Sending notifications');

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(Object.keys(allToken.val()), payload, options)
});
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to describe the problem you're experiencing?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenshot of where the device token is being stored

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsDSh.png